# Video blank on boot

Tags: kms

Booting Ubuntu 14.10 on tablet with Intel Z3740 CPU, but when booting without nomodeset parameter, video blinks and goes black (backlight seems to be still on) after this message:

```
fb: switching to inteldrmfb from EFI VGA
```

Is there any way to debug boot after screen goes dark and there's no way to get console output?
After quite a few boot ups it seems to work randomly, but successul boot is very rare.

Answer (score 0):

You probabaly have a broken **xorg.conf** file.

Open a tty by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and type the following commands and login using your username and password.

Now type the following command :

`sudo dexconf -o /etc/X11/xorg.conf`

This will generate a new xorg.conf file.

Comment: I think issue happens way before Xorg starts. And I cannot switch to other tty, as screen is blank. But I managed to login and execute poweroff blindly, so it seems system is not frozen.

Comment: Oh, okay. Makes sense now. It's a graphic card driver issue. I had the same problem with my Fedora 20. I could solve it by installing the proprietary graphic drivers on my laptop.